# Подключение *.pas файла к проекту в C++ Builder

Tags: c++, delphi, c++builder

Имеется проект в C++ Builder, также имеется файл формата .pas содержащий довольно большое количество нужного кода. Переписывать его на C++ очень не охота. Каким образом можно подключить паскалевский файл к сppшному проекту?

Comment: ВОзможно, это Вам подойдет
`http://www.mpsinc.com/pas2cpp.html`
`http://www.garret.ru/ptoc`

Answer (score 5):

Простейшим путем использования модуля Delphi является его добавление в проект. Ниже приведены шаги, необходимые для добавления модуля Delphi в проект C++Builder'а:

- Создайте в C++Builder'е свой проект.
- Выберите "Add to Project" в панели C ++ Builder 'а или в меню.
- Выберите "Pascal unit" в типах файлов выпадающего списка диалогового
  окна открытия файлов.
- Выберите модуль Delphi для добавления в свой проект и нажмите OK.
- Перестройте свое приложение перед написанием кода, ссылающегося на
  модуль Delphi. Перестройка проекта создаст из модуля заголовок,
  который вы сможете включить в свое приложение.
- Выберите пункт "File / Include Unit Hdr…" в главном меню C++Builder
  'а и добавьте форму Delphi в ваше приложение.
- Напишите код, который ссылается на модуль Delphi.

Когда вы перестраиваете приложение, C++Builder использует встроенный компилятор паскаля для создания obj -файла, который приложение сможет использовать. Компилятор паскаля также создает заголовочный файл из исходного текста.

Answer (score -1):

Можно скомпилировать Pascal/Delphi код в DLL и подключить/задействовать эту DLL в C++ приложении.

Comment: А можно немного подробнее? Каким образом этот код в DLL скомпилировать?

Comment: На общий вопрос - общий ответ. Уточняйте вопрос. В каком виде у вас этот код, только ли функции, или классы, глобальные переменные, использование внешних зависимостей и т.п.. Приводите примеры.

Comment: Только функции.